# How to use internet from another basic mobile through bluetooth?

Tags: data-connection, bluetooth-tethering

How to connect an android phone with the basic phone having unlimited data packs . How to use the data on their phone in android using bluetooth?

Answer (score 1):

If that basic mobile has the future of bluetooth hotspot, you can make use of that. Otherwise it can't be done as per your requirements.

Answer (score 0):

If it does not have to be Bluetooth, but WiFi would make you happy as well: For quite a while now, Android offers a nice feature called *Hotspot*. The one with the unlimited mobile data starts that on his device, and everybody with WiFi capabilities can use it like any other WiFi hotspot ­– if they are told the connection data (WiFi password and hotspot name).

Comment: Another mobile is just a basic mobile without WiFi

Comment: This doesn't answer the question.

Answer (score 0):

Try using bluetooth PAN (Personal Area Network).  Some bluethooth adapters with third party drivers have excellent features to deploy and maintain a PAN.  Internet sharing is possible over Bluetooth. You will need another PC to establish such a network.  Both the basic and android phone will connect over bluetooth.

Answer (score 0):

Use Easy Tether Pro. It enables an Android to share data connection through bluetooth with another Android.

Comment: This post may answer the question, but if any apps are mentioned, it is standard practice to link to their websites/hosts at least once in the post per app.